# How to configure solr(4.10) for multiple words auto suggestion?

Tags: solr, autosuggest, search-multiple-words

I want to create collection with auto suggestion in Solr, i tried for single word its working fine but am looking for phrases for example if we type "Barack" its should come "Barack", "Barack Obama","Barack Obama president of USA".

I have 6 fields but want to give suggestion for one filed only (i.e..Content), how to configure schema.xml and solr config.xml according to this fields. I've tried ton of examples but that didn't work for me!
Have any simple solution for this?? Any help would be appreciate !
Thanks in Advance.

Thanks Amit for response, I tried that also but didnt get What I was looking for 
   my schema.xml is like this I want the suggestion on my Content field 
   and my solr config is given below !

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"   multiValued="false" />
   <field name="Content" type="suggest_phrase" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="Lang" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="PubDate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="Section" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="PaperName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="Page_No" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" />

  <fieldType name="suggest_phrase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>


    <!-- search content -->
  <searchComponent name="suggest_phrase" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest_phrase</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookup</str>
        <str name="field">suggest_phrase</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest_phrase">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest_phrase</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest_phrase</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shingle on the field which you are using for the auto-suggestion.

Comment: Hi Aman, as you said I tried with the Shinglefilterfactory, but didn't get what i was looking for !
any other solution??